# Show that $f_n\to 0$ in the distributional sense.

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f_n(x)=\sin{(nx)}$. Show that $f_n\to 0$ in the distributional sense.

I know that this is true only if $\langle f_n,\phi\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_n\phi\to \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f\phi=\langle f,\phi\rangle$ for any test function $\phi$. In this case the 2nd integral equals $0$.

My question is how to go about implementing this. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: @Jonas : or integration by part ?

Comment: @user1952009 How would you go about integration by parts?

Comment: @DesperateFluffy :  $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(nx) \phi(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n} \phi'(x) dx$ where $\phi'(x)$ is also a test function ? (this is how is proved the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma#Proof )

Comment: @user1952009 I'm sorry, but I don't understand how that helps me.

Comment: since $\phi'$ is a test function, no problem for writing $|\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n} \phi'(x) dx | < \frac{1}{n} \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\phi'(x)| dx$

Comment: @user1952009 I think I'm missing something. Integrating by parts $\int \sin{(nx)}\phi(x)dx$ yields $-\frac{\cos{(nx)}}{n}\phi(x)|_{\mathbb{R}} +\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\cos{(nx)}}{n} \phi^{\prime}(x)dx$, but you said $\int \sin{(nx)}\phi(x)dx=\int \frac{\cos{(nx)}}{n}\phi^{\prime}(x)dx$.  Why?

Comment: :D  the integration by part is much simpler because $\phi$ is smooth and has a compact support (it is a test function). that's all the point of considering test functions.

Comment: maybe you didn't understand what is a test function ? you can't write  down any one easily, because it is not analytic. it is a function which is $C^\infty$ on $[a,b]$ and $0$ outside, but which stays analytic even at $a,b$ and hence on $\mathbb{R}$. and for understanding that those exist, you will need the fact that for example with $f(t) = e^{-1/t}$, $\lim_{t \to 0^+} f^{(k)}(t) = 0$, hence at the left of $t=0$ you can say that $f(t) = 0$, and you will get that $f(t)$ is $C^\infty$ on $\mathbb{R}$. repeating the same kind of trick at $t=b$, you'll get an example of test function.

Comment: So when a test function is evaluated over the entirety of $\mathbb{R}$, because it is 0 outside of some bounded set, the evaluation is 0?

Comment: you should read a course on test functions, for constructing an example of, then everything will be much more clear.

Comment: Any recommendations?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function